# How does Boost.Python hold C++ class?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I know how to use Boost.Python to wrap a C++ class exposing to Python.
It's really powerful for using Boost.Python to do wrapping things so conveniently.

However, few details is explained about how does Boost.Python **hold** a C++ class.

The code of Boost.Python is hard to read or debug, for it's written in a template meta programming fashion and all things just *execute* during compile time. I've scaned the documentation and "Building Hybrid Systems With Boost Python" article by the authors, yet didn't find the answer.

**So, how does Boost.Python hold C++ class?**

Does it hold the wrapped C++ class instance as a private member of `PyObject`? Are all the inheritance, polymorphic etc. features of a wrapped class mimicked by delegating to the held instance?

Answer (score 0):

> So, how does Boost.Python hold C++ class?

To be pedantic, in C++ there are no classes at run-time, only objects or instances of a class.

Boost class wrappers hold your C++ objects either by value or via a smart pointer (currently only deprecated `std::auto_ptr` is supported).

Unfortunately boost.python documentation is rather lacking, here are some useful links for you:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/test/select_holder.cpp
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/test/auto_ptr.cpp
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/faq.html#ownership

Comment: *"currently only deprecated std::auto_ptr is supported"* — is this still true in 2021?